# findByIdAndUpdate With Multiple Subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I'm working with NodeJS and MongoDB, and I'm making an endpoint that lets clients update their user profiles with several optional data fields. So, one of the update queries can look like this:

```
{ 
    name: { givenName: 'first' },
    about: 'whatever',
    auth: { password: 'hashedPW' } 
}
```

The Mongoose API docs state the following info about `findByIdAndUpdate`: All top level update keys which are not atomic operation names are treated as set operations.

So the top level key, `about`, works fine to update. However, the nested keys, `name` and `auth` are overwritten by the update values, rather than just having the values set.

Now I could go through and manually change each of the fields to be a `$set` key, but there are a lot of different fields, so to do this would be pretty annoying. Is there an easy way to apply the $set rule to the subdocuments as well? i.e. transform the statement into this, with a Mongoose option or something:

```
{ 
    $set : { name: { givenName: 'first' } },
    $set : { about: 'whatever' },
    $set : { auth: { password: 'hashedPW' } } 
}
```

Comment: You normally should be able to just add the full object as second parameter...

Comment: Based on the documentation's wording, I don't think this is the case; I think it only applies for top level keys. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: I don't have a computer atm so I can't test it. Most of the time I work with *update* instead of *findByIdAndUpdate* and that works for nested keys.

Comment: `$set` is already used by default by mongoose. But to prevent overwriting embedded fields, use dot notation: `{'name.givenName': 'first',... }`

Comment: @hassansin Since I'm trying to make this a blanket "update" endpoint, I wanted to literally take the input, and apply it to mongoose without requiring the user to formulate their query in Mongo-style string. Is there a way to convert a javascript object into dot notation that would work?

Comment: If that's the case you can use this: https://github.com/hughsk/flat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to tranform your input object into ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document/#dot-notation) form in order to avoid overwring other possible sub-keys in your update. This is quite simple really:

```js
var obj = { 
    name: { givenName: 'first' },
    about: 'whatever',
    auth: { password: 'hashedPW' } 
};

var target = {};

function dotNotate(obj,prefix) {
  prefix = (typeof(prefix) === 'undefined') ? "" : prefix;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if ( typeof(obj[key]) === "object" ) {
      dotNotate(obj[key],key + ".")
    } else {
      target[prefix + key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
}

dotNotate(obj);
```

Now the `target` object looks like this:

```js
{
    "name.givenName" : "first",
    "about" : "whatever",
    "auth.password" : "hashedPW"
}
```

So the update block of your statement is merely written as:

```js
{ "$set": target }
```

---

For reference, the `dotNotate()` function can be a bit more refined and self contained. Also including shorter default assignments as valid input would generally be considered be "truthy". Also the "prefix" should have been pre-pended on each call to make this work at arbitrary depth:

```js
function dotNotate(obj,target,prefix) {
  target = target || {},
  prefix = prefix || "";

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if ( typeof(obj[key]) === "object" ) {
      dotNotate(obj[key],target,prefix + key + ".");
    } else {
      return target[prefix + key] = obj[key];
    }
  });

  return target;
}
```

Then you can use either inline:

```js
var update = { "$set": dotNotate(obj) };
```

Or pass in a defined object like this if you prefer:

```js
var update = { "$set": {} };
dotNotate(obj,update["$set"]);
```

With the same results.

Also fine for arrays and nested depth:

```js
{
    "things" : [
        {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 2
        },
        {
            "a" : 3,
            "b" : 4
        }
    ],
    "bool" : false
}
```

With output:

```js
{
    "things.0.a" : 1,
    "things.0.b" : 2,
    "things.1.a" : 3,
    "things.1.b" : 4,
    "bool" : false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the answer marked as correct, you should flatten your object, converting it into dot-notation before passing it to mongoose.

There a nice package to do this now, called `dot-wild`:
https://github.com/wadackel/dot-wild

With this one you can just do:

```js
import * as dot from 'dot-wild'

dot.flatten(object)
```

Example taken from their docs:

```js
const postData = {
  text: 'ok',
  code: 200,
  data: {
    posts: [
      { id: 1, title: 'post 1' },
      { id: 2, title: 'post 2' }
    ],
    tags: [
      { id: 1, name: 'tag 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'tag 2' }
    ]
  }
};


/**
 * Flatten values
 */
dot.flatten(postData);
// => {
//      text: 'ok',
//      code: 200,
//      'data.posts.0.id': 1,
//      'data.posts.0.title': 'post 1',
//      'data.posts.1.id': 2,
//      'data.posts.1.title': 'post 2',
//      'data.tags.0.id': 1,
//      'data.tags.0.name': 'tag 1',
//      'data.tags.1.id': 2,
//      'data.tags.1.name': 'tag 2'
//    }
```